# Safari keeps losing my sessions / cookies

Tags: safari, cookies

I'm a long-time Safari user, without any serious troubles.
As of yesterday, Safari now loses my session data every half hour or so.  Meaning - I get logged out of all of the sites I'm logged into - Google, Twitter, Stack Exchange, whatever.  They all seem to get logged out at the same time, and it happens many times a day.

I don't think that I made any changes that would impact this.

Any insight?

Comment: What version of Safari? Any new plugins?

Comment: Safari v. 7.0.2.  Only extension is Ultimate Status Bar 1.3.    The issue appears to have calmed down - after a restart and a network location change, I'm not seeing the issue.

Comment: I have this issue on Safari 8, and restarting hasn't helped. I only have AdBlock enabled. When I look at my cookies file, its created date gets reset whenever this happens, and of course it has almost nothing in it.

Comment: I'm getting something similar with Safari 9.1.3 but only resets every few days, have Instapaper, Ghostery and ClickToFlash/Plugin. But none of these are new and the problems started a week ago.